# How to handled the null values in WHERE IN condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to include the possible values as null in where in condition in mysql query. 
Here is my query: But it is not displaying any values. Please suggest me how to include the null value in WHERE IN condition.

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 IN ('YES','NO',NULL);
```

Comment: What are the other values beside yes, no and null? Maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like :

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE (COLUMN1 IN ('YES', 'NO') OR COLUMN1 IS NULL)
```

Here in statement will be parsed like COLUMN1='YES' or COLUMN1='NO' or field='NULL'. Putting a NULL in there will get you COLUMN1=null which won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 IN ('YES','NO') OR COLUMN1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this this:

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 IS NULL OR COLUMN1 IN ('YES','NO');